# trying to make a calculator but my first function(addition) isnt working as intended

Tags: python, calc

This is my first time messing around with functions and I'm trying to make a calculator.

I have made 4 functions - each set for add, subtract, multiply and divide.

I have 2 inputs for x and y and an operations variable for the calculator to take in.

you can see the code I got so far below.

when I enter the two numbers let's say 5 and 5 for now choose "add". it will spit out 55. can anyone enlighten me on why and how I counter this as well as any tips for refining/improving the current code.

any help is appreciated, please be nice :)

```
def add(x, y):
    print(x+y)
    return
def subtract(x, y):
    print(x-y)
    return
def multiply(x, y):
    print(x*y)
    return
def divide(x, y):
    print(x/y)
    return

x = input("Enter number:")
y = input("Enter number:")
operation = input("Enter operation: ")

if operation == "add":
    add(x,y)
```

Comment: You forgot to convert `x` and `y` to integers, so `+` is doing string concatenation, not addition of integers. Change `x = input("Enter number:")` to `x = int(input("Enter number:"))` and make a similar change reading `y`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input you receive from the user is in the form of a string - `'5'`. When you add two strings together, they simply concatenate - `'5' + '5'` results in `'55`.

If you want the inputs to be converted to numbers, you need to make that conversion explicit using `int` or `float`. You can then add them up and have it behave the way you want. Like so:

```
x = int(input("Enter number:"))
y = int(input("Enter number:"))
```